# Center four columns in CSS

Tags: center, css

I'm trying to make four columns that are centered on the frontpage. I would like it to look like this example:
http://www.clutterpad.com/

My code looks like this:

```
#bottom-container {width:100%;height:250px;position:relative;}
#bottom-mid {background-color:white;}
#bottom-left, #bottom-mid, #bottom-right {height:250px;}
#bottom-left, #bottom-right {width:50%;float:left;}

#bottom-left {background-color:white;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;}
#bottom-right {background-color:white;position:absolute;top:0px;left:50%;}

#bottom-mid {position:relative;margin:0px auto; width:1000px;z-index:2;}
#column-container {width:100%; margin:20px auto;}
.column {width:200px;float:left;font-size:10pt;font-family:Arial;margin:20px 10px;}
```

But it's not working out. How should I code it to look like the example I mentioned before?

Answer (score 3):

It would be good if you could include the HTML, but I would approach the problem like this:

```
<div id="fourcolumns">
    <div>Column</div>
    <div>Column</div>
    <div>Column</div>
    <div>Column</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fourcolumns {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#fourcolumns div {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

If you are adding margins between the columns, you will fall victim to the IE6 double margin float bug, which you can fix by including `#fourcolumns div { display: inline; }`

Answer (score -1):

```
<div id="fourcolumns"> 
    <div>Column</div> 
    <div>Column</div> 
    <div>Column</div> 
    <div>Column</div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#fourcolumns { 
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 50%; 
    overflow: hidden; 
} 

#fourcolumns div { 
    width: 25%; 
    float: left; 
}
```

Comment: Nice. Copy and paste most of my answer.